# Wrong code logic for processing large number of files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dataset, ocr

I am a beginner and new to python and Image processing. For a college project I was trying to train character recognition for a regional language. I have a data-set which is very huge (approx 90000 images). The part of the code below is for extracting images to a data-set. However when I run the code it exhausts my 8gb RAM and my pc freezes. This may be due to processing a large number of images.

> My PC Specs: Intel Core I5 8th Gen 8GB RAM NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1060
>   6GB.

Is there any workaround for this so that I can run it on my PC? Any help will be appreciated.

```
%matplotlib inline


root_dir = os.getcwd()
img_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, 'images')

pixels = np.array(['pixel_{:04d}'.format(x) for x in range(1024)])
flag = True

for char_name in sorted(os.listdir(img_dir)):
    char_dir = os.path.join(img_dir, char_name)
    img_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pixels)

    for img_file in sorted(os.listdir(char_dir)):
        image = pd.Series(imageio.imread(os.path.join(char_dir, img_file)).flatten(), index=pixels)
        img_df = img_df.append(image.T, ignore_index=True)

    img_df = img_df.astype(np.uint8)
    img_df['character'] = char_name

    img_df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=flag)
    flag=False

    print('=', end='')


df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df['character_class'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df.character)
df.drop('character', axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: I see that you are using data frames. What library are you actually using for training? Maybe it does not have to accept a humongous data frame full of images.

Comment: I am actually trying to use this [link](https://github.com/rishianand54/devanagari-character-recognition-system)

Comment: I see that you manually creating a progress bar. You should look for `tqdm` package, it will make you life easier.

Comment: Well pardon me if I'm wrong, but appending large content to `.csv` files is very memory consuming. I would save in separate CSVs. Ultimately, I would use pickles since it is a faster serialization than strings.

Comment: I thing the problem is the the code is trying to first read all images into RAM and then process them, instead of reading one image, process it, drop the loaded image, read the next image, process it, and so on.

Comment: Thanks @mr_mo. Actually I am a beginner and don't know how to use pickles. Can u help me with it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your code, it seems like you are appending many images to the same dataframe for your inner loop, then overwriting the same csv in the outer loop. Can you avoid appending to the same dataframe? Just a guess, but that might be where you are hitting memory ceiling.

Comment: @BMW indeed appending to a `.csv` file is VERY memory consuming and time consuming. One need to iterate all lines and look for EOF before inserting the content. After few characters, I guess that this is what jamming this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I do not the root cause of your problem, I'll add some notes from my experience in working with large datasets.

1. Text files, CSV among them, are expensive in terms of disk space, memory (strings) and processing (reading, parsing and casting to other types). Every time `pandas` reads a CSV file, it reads it line by line, parse the next and construct python objects. This is time consuming.
2. Large text files, specifically large `.csv` files, doesn't work well with pandas. I really can't point for the exact reason, but I couldn't load more than 2GB csv file into a dataframe with a 16GB ram machine.
3. Good serialization of the data is always better than a general one. However, `pickle` is a pretty general python object serialization method that performs well with many type of objects. Sure, it has vulnerabilities, bla bla bla. For pure python research work it is great *easy* way to save your objects. Panda's DataFrame integrated it among other ways to save your object. Use `df.to_pickle('/path/to/file.pkl')
4. Huge file is a single point of failure. I think it is better to have several files and to use a proper data reader for your task.

Having said that, here is my

```
%matplotlib inline


root_dir = os.getcwd()
img_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, 'images')

pixels = np.array(['pixel_{:04d}'.format(x) for x in range(1024)])
flag = True
chars = sorted(os.listdir(img_dir))

for char_name in chars:
    char_dir = os.path.join(img_dir, char_name)
    img_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pixels)

    for img_file in sorted(os.listdir(char_dir)):
        image = pd.Series(imageio.imread(os.path.join(char_dir, img_file)).flatten(), index=pixels)
        img_df = img_df.append(image.T, ignore_index=True)

    img_df = img_df.astype(np.uint8)
    img_df['character'] = char_name

    img_df.to_pickle(f'{char_name}_data.pkl')
    flag=False

    print('=', end='')


df = pd.concat([pd.read_pickle(f'{char_name}_data.pkl') for char_name in chars],axis=0)

df['character_class'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df.character)
df.drop('character', axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.astype(np.uint8)
```

Alternatively, you can still use a single file by appending your dataframe and saving the final:

```
%matplotlib inline


root_dir = os.getcwd()
img_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, 'images')

pixels = np.array(['pixel_{:04d}'.format(x) for x in range(1024)])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['character'] + pixels.tolist())
for char_name in sorted(os.listdir(img_dir)):
    char_dir = os.path.join(img_dir, char_name)
    img_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pixels)

    for img_file in sorted(os.listdir(char_dir)):
        image = pd.Series(imageio.imread(os.path.join(char_dir, img_file)).flatten(), index=pixels)
        img_df = img_df.append(image.T, ignore_index=True)

    img_df = img_df.astype(np.uint8)
    img_df['character'] = char_name
    df.append(image_df)
    print('=', end='')

df.to_pickle('data.pkl')
df = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')

df['character_class'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df.character)
df.drop('character', axis=1, inplace=True)
df = df.astype(np.uint8)
```

Please let me know if this solve your problem.
It seems like a small issue but I know that sort of things can be time consuming to debug.

P.S.
Since you use magic, I assume you use Jupyter. 
Your machine is +/- a laptop; I would suggest closing all running kernels in your jupyter notebook/lab and use only one when working with large data.